# Obtaining a pandas dataframe from a dict with tuples as keys

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dictionary

I am new to python and have been struggling with this problem for quite a while. I have a dict like this:

`dict1 = {(a,a) : 5, (a,b) :10, (a,c) : 11, (b,a): 4, (b,b) : 8, (b,c) : 3....}`

What I would like to do is convert this into a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    a    b    c
a   5    10   11
b   4    8    3
c   ..   ..   ..
```

After that I would like to create a multiple bar plot in the jupyter notebook. I know you can display the data as a pandas series to show the following:

```
dataset = pd.Series(dict1)
print dataset
    a  a  5
       b  10
       c  11
    b  a  4
       b  8
       c  3
    c  a  ..
       b  ..
       c  ..
```

However, I was not able to create a multiple bar plot from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, just need to [unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking):

```
dataset.unstack()
```

I prefer to use this [page](https://web.archive.org/web/20161029015223/http://nikgrozev.com/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/) for reference, rather than the official documentation.