# Processing large dictionary and data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, bigdata

I have two `pandas` data frame with shape `(2500, 2500)`, the data frame looks like this:

```
>> df1
    "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" 
"o"  0   0   0   0   0
"p"  0   0   0   0   0
"q"  0   0   0   0   0
"r"  0   0   0   0   0
"s"  0   0   0   0   0
```

And I have two dictionaries with '~2,000,000' key, value pairs. It looks like this

```
d1 = {("a", "o"):3, ("b", "p"):10}
```

I am trying to fill in the values in the dictionary to the data frame. My solution right now is to loop through the dictionary:

```
for key, value in d1.iteritems():
    df1.loc[key[0], key[1]] = value
```

However this process is taking a very long time. I am wondering if there is a way i can go through the dictionary more efficiently. Or if I should change the way of storing the data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First DataFrame is filled `0` only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtaining a pandas dataframe from a dict with tuples as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202580/obtaining-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-dict-with-tuples-as-keys)

Comment: @jezrael yes that's correct

Comment: @KiwiFT - Then use second solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create `Series`, then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for `DataFrame`, transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and last [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) for assign values of `df1`:

```
d1 = {("a", "o"):3, ("b", "p"):10}
df = pd.Series(d1).unstack().T.combine_first(df1)
print (df)
     a     b    c    d    e
o  3.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
p  0.0  10.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
q  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
r  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
s  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

If `df1` is filled by `0` only use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `index` and `columns` of `df1`:

```
df = (pd.Series(d1)
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .T
        .reindex(index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns, fill_value=0))
print (df)
   a   b  c  d  e
o  3   0  0  0  0
p  0  10  0  0  0
q  0   0  0  0  0
r  0   0  0  0  0
s  0   0  0  0  0
```

Comment: I just tried this, with the first approach reading a dictionary with a million entires took ~30s and with the second approach it's ~14s. Thank you so much!